# The New Dungeon lengthening

Tags: house-rules

Now and again I play the The New Dungeon (with people who don't normally play board games), but I'm always struck by how fast the game is over. It seems like you're barely getting started on the higher levels before someone's off back to the staircase with a winning bagful of loot.

Does anyone have any simple custom rules for lengthening the game, or even to make it more interesting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, I was just looking at this game again the other day, too funny.

While I haven't played in a few years, I do remember our group has used one (or both) of he following rules to make things play longer:

1. Increase by 50% or 100% (depending on how long you want the game to play) the amount of loot necessary to win the game.
2. Require that in addition to collecting enough loot, you must have collected at least one piece of treasure from each floor, or from a specified number of floors.